# No signature of method is applicable for argument types

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to use `buildConfigField` to add a variable for my Android build. Here is the relevant code in my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    flavorDimensions "tier"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bbct.android.common"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
        buildConfigField "String" "BASE_URL" "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/"
    }
// ...
}
```

When I sync this, I get

> No signature of method: build_4witj2n6904v9rh151cgl0ygr.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_4witj2n6904v9rh151cgl0ygr$_run_closure2) values: [build_4witj2n6904v9rh151cgl0ygr$_run_closure2@5e3edf4f]

Without the `buildConfigField` line, I don't get any errors. How do I correctly use `buildConfigField` to add this variable?

Comment: Commas: `buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/"`.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm not surprised I was missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: The Java won't compile, you need wrap the value with ": `buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/\""`

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel Thanks for the tip. The error I was asking about was solved by adding commas. The missing quotes causes a totally different error.